# How to mimic iOS settings page layout

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

I'm developing for iOS using Xamarin.iOS. I don't have much experience with it but I did some research and I couldn't find much information on the subject (maybe I'm using the wrong keywords). Anyway, how can I mimic the iOS settings page layout?

I'm creating an application that's got this huge form and I'd like to adopt the iOS settings page layout since it seems to solve that problem elegantly.

Is that a table view with inputs?

Does anyone know?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a `UITableView`, yes.

The easiest way to create something like this (if you don't need dynamic content) is to add a table view into a Storyboard and use static cells, which can be designed directly in the visual editor.

For a more dynamic approach you'll have to assign a source to the table and implement `GetCell()` to return the appropriate content. We have documentation over [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/general/storyboard/storyboard_a_tableview/).

Comment: Thank you. And do you have any documentation on how I can make the cells/inputs look like the one on the settings page? Thanks again!

Comment: That's IMHO the default styles provided by iOS combined with accessories (info button, disclosure indicator, ...)